# Weird Issue with IE File Download

Tags: java, internet-explorer-8, download

We've written a file download service.
On the client side, the download is attempted by Javascript. We create a dynamic form and a dynamic iframe and set the forms target to be the iframe.

On the Server Side we have the Content-Disposition header set.

This works in FF/Chrome and > IE9. For IE8 However, I see the download executes properly, the prompt comes up on IE8, but the file never downloads.

This is how it actually looks.

[image: Download Prompt]

And this continues on forever. It never ends.

[image: File Download Goes on Forever]

No File Save As prompt shows up.

I have tried changing the Content-Disposition Headers, experimented with flushing/closing response objects, changing content types...

Code on the server side is in the following form

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".xlsx");

//Calls some export function that returns an outputstream.
exportStream = export();

OutputStream responseStream = response.getOutputStream();
responseStream.write(exportStream.toByteArray());

responseStream.flush();
responseStream.close();
exportStream.flush();
exportStream.close();
```

I have no idea why this is happening and it is killing me now x-(

Comment: Do you send `Content-Length` header?

Comment: Did not. Let me try that with IE8.

Comment: @izstas: That did solve the problem. I'll test more anyway. Do you mind putting that as an answer, so I can give you credit for it?

Comment: Except now, if I remove the Content-Length header, it is mysteriously working. And the only difference between yesterday and now, is a restart of this laptop. x-(

Comment: I'd like to make sure that this indeed solves the problem. Does it work stable with having `Content-Length`?

Comment: `Content-Length` addition or removal has no effect. Now it works with or without that header. I think the issue was not related to programming per se. A restart solved the issue...now everything seems to work as intended. Therefore I must apologize for the untested response.